# After upgrade to 21.10 cannot record screen with Kazam or SimpleScreenRecorder or Vokoscreen

Tags: wayland, 21.10, desktop-recording, kazam

I upgrade the ubuntu from 20.04 to 21.10. Now i cannot make a record of the screen. The image keep stay full black. It records the mouse pointer and audio but not the video of the desktop.

I already tried with Kazam, SimpleScreenRecorder and Vokoscreen. Only the Vokoscreen 3.0.7 gave a warning: detected session with Wayland working area. At this moment Wayland is not supported. A transmission shows a black screen. Please leave this account and start a area session with X11.

Any clues to solve this problem? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I submitted a bug in Kazam and checked how to change from Wayland to X11.After this, all screen recorders started to work as expected.

Comment: Can you please elaborate how to do it?